# Question about inverse Z-Transform

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

Assume I a discrete signal with Z-transform $$ \frac{Z^{N+1}-1}{Z^{N+1}-Z^{N}} $$

Is there a reasonable way to know all the possible options for the original discrete signal? (we do not know the ROC, so any choice for the ROC would lead to difefrent signal). $N $ is some integer which we also do not know. My initial thought was to write:

$$ \frac{Z^{N+1}-1}{Z^{N+1}-Z^{N}}=\frac{\left(Z-1\right)\left(1+Z+Z^{2}+...+Z^{N}\right)}{\left(Z-1\right)Z^{N}}=\frac{1}{Z^{N}}+\frac{1}{Z^{N-1}}+...+1 $$

Can narrow the possibilites for the original signals from this point?

I feel like there's somethingg I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It  seems you've got it right: as you used in your simplification, every choice that simplifies to the same term works. But all of these have but one representation as a *causal* signal.

Comment: I assune that this one representation is the Kroneker delta? (Up to shifting).

Comment: No that's your final line! The first N+1 samples are 1. The rest is 0.

Comment: @mm isnt it the same as the sum of N+1 Kroneker's delta?

Comment: Every single possible discrete signal with that many elements that are not zero is. This is special!